# actionButton in server side modularized code does not work

Tags: r, shiny, modularization

I am using a modalDialog pop up to allow an issue to be recorded in the github api. However, as the `actionButton("ok", "Submit new issue")` is in the modularized server side code, I believe due to it not being name spaced the button does not work. I have provided a test code below which should show the title when the button is pressed but it doesn't do anything.

Is there any way around it?

```
library(shiny)

editTableUI <- function(id){
  ns<-NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("add_issue"), "New Issue"),
    textOutput("text"))
  }
  
editTable <-function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$add_issue, {
    loginModal <- function() {
      modalDialog(
        title = "Create Issue",
        textInput("title", "Title"),
        textAreaInput("body", "Body", placeholder = "Leave a comment", width = '100%', height = '300px' ),
        selectInput("asignee",label= "Assignees", selected = NULL, choices = c("a","b","c","d"), multiple = T ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Cancel"),
          actionButton("ok", "Submit new issue")),
        fade = T,
        size = c("s")
        )
    }
    showModal(loginModal())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
  output$text <- renderText({ input$title })})
  
}
  

ui <- fluidPage(
  editTableUI("tab2"))
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(editTable, "tab2")}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: where the `Table` variable???

Comment: I put the wrong code during the transfer, my bad. I have edited it now. Should have been `textOutput("text")`. @PorkChop

Comment: Again what is `input$create` ??? and where is it?, should that be `input$ok` ???

Comment: The issue is the button. This code is to just provide an example. However, I have edited the `input$ok` as well thank you. @PorkChop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean now, when you are working with modules and creating objects inside the modules, you need to assign the namespace to them e.g. `session$ns("ok")`, then you can access them like so: `session$input$ok`, similar for the `title` input you have, the code below should work for you...

```
library(shiny)

editTableUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        actionButton(ns("add_issue"), "New Issue"),
        textOutput(ns("text"))
    )
}

editTable <-function(input, output, session){
    
    observeEvent(input$add_issue, {
        loginModal <- function() {
            modalDialog(
                title = "Create Issue",
                textInput(session$ns("title"), "Title"),
                textAreaInput("body", "Body", placeholder = "Leave a comment", width = '100%', height = '300px' ),
                selectInput("asignee",label= "Assignees", selected = NULL, choices = c("a","b","c","d"), multiple = T ),
                footer = tagList(
                    modalButton("Cancel"),
                    actionButton(session$ns("ok"), "Submit new issue")),
                fade = T,
                size = c("s")
            )
        }
        showModal(loginModal())
    })
    
    observeEvent(session$input$ok, {
        output$text <- renderText({ 
            input$title 
        })
    })
    
}


ui <- fluidPage(
    editTableUI("tab2"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(editTable, "tab2")
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```